# Defining controlling parameters for graphs globally in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

To control the size of graph in `knitr` I use the following code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
<< label = Plot1, fig.width=5, fig.height=5, out.width=.7\linewidth, fig.keep = all>>=
...
@
    \caption{Plot}
    \label{fig:figPlot1}
\end{figure}
```

I wonder how to define these controlling parameters for graphs globally instead for defining each graph. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: a side comment: for `\centering`, you can actually use the chunk option `fig.align='center'` (with knitr 0.3) to center plots so that you do not need to do this in LaTeX; what is more, `\centering` may have side effects to other output since its applied to all elements before `\end{figure}`, and `fig.align='center'` is safer; it only center plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
\SweaveOpts{fig.width=5, fig.height=5, out.width=".7\\linewidth", fig.keep = "all"}
```

?  I have modified these to work with knitr version 0.3, which requires that option values be in valid R syntax ...

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bloker for your answer. I already tried this `\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
<< label = Plot1>>=
...
@
    \caption{Plot}
    \label{fig:figPlot1}
\end{figure}` but got the following error: `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :
’match’ requires vector arguments`. Any suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in `...`? What is the version of knitr? You may need to update it (the latest version on CRAN is 0.3; see `update.packages()`)

Comment: @Yihui: Yes there is no error in `...`. Everything works fine when I use parameters for individual plot and I'm using the development version of `knitr`.

Comment: OK, can you start a new R session and run `knit()` in it? if the error still occurs, see if you can work out a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!